# Vite build and Global Vue 3 Components via Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue-component, vuejs3, vite

This question could be answered by fixing the typescript error or how best to handle global Vue 3 component registrations with Typescript.  In a nutshell, if I run `npm run dev` (vite) the dev server runs fine and there are no issues.  When trying to produce a build via `npm run build` (vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build) the following error occurs:

> src/main.ts:15:17 - error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
>
> 15   app.component(Components[key].name, Components[key]);

A little background, all components I had were created based on the [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components) and use of `defineComponent`. An example is below.  At some point, several components needed to be registered globally because they are used throughout the entire application.

```
<script lang="ts">
//sbutton.vue
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "s-button",
  props: {
    disabled: {
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    },
    loading: {
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    }
  },
  computed:{
    disableBtn(): Boolean {
      return this.loading || this.disabled;
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

I took the global components and consolidated them to an object that I could run through and register globally.

```
// components/index.ts

import BlogSubscribe from './BlogSubscribe.vue';
import SButton from './SButton.vue';

const components = {
    BlogSubscribe,
    SButton
};

export default components;
```

And finally registered them globally in main.ts:

```
import Components from './components';

const app = createApp(App).use(router);

for (const key in Components) {
  app.component(Components[key].name, Components[key]);  // <- error here
}
```

To recap, usuing vue3, vite, typescript what is the best process for registering a group of global components in order to produce a build version of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way but not sure it is the best nor recommended way to handle global vue component registrations with vite/vue3.

```
const components:{[index:string]: Component<any, any, any, ComputedOptions, MethodOptions>} = {
   [BlogSubscribe.name]: BlogSubscribe,
    [SButton.name]: SButton
};

export default components;
```

and in main.ts:

```
for (const key in Components) {
  app.component(key, Components[key]);
}
```